# What can i use for replacing InMemoryRandomAccessStream in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

i know there are two classes for IRandomAccessStream interface in WinRT,
FileRandomAccessStream and InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

now i'm porting one of my apps to wp8 and some of my methods need IRandomAccessStream as return type,but i cannot find InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

how can i create a memorystream and get a IRandomAccessStream from it without InMemoryRandomAccessStream in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

ran into the same thing. I ended up using a temp file stream with random access.

This is kludged together from

[windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder) which is not actually implemented, so I created a file in the localfolder instead (make sure to delete it after, since you want something temporary?).

and

[windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream)

here it is the slightly adopted sample code:

```
        private async void TransferData()//object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder temporaryFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        // Write data to a file
        StorageFile sampleFile = await temporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("tempStream.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream acccessStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        // Initialize the in-memory stream where data will be stored.
        using (var stream = acccessStream)
        {
            // Create the data writer object backed by the in-memory stream.
            using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(stream))
            {
                dataWriter.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                dataWriter.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

                // Parse the input stream and write each element separately.
                string[] inputElements = "this;really;works".Split(';');
                foreach (string inputElement in inputElements)
                {
                    uint inputElementSize = dataWriter.MeasureString(inputElement);
                    dataWriter.WriteUInt32(inputElementSize);
                    dataWriter.WriteString(inputElement);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Wrote: " + inputElement);
                }

                // Send the contents of the writer to the backing stream.
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

                // For the in-memory stream implementation we are using, the flushAsync call 
                // is superfluous,but other types of streams may require it.
                await dataWriter.FlushAsync();

                // In order to prolong the lifetime of the stream, detach it from the 
                // DataWriter so that it will not be closed when Dispose() is called on 
                // dataWriter. Were we to fail to detach the stream, the call to 
                // dataWriter.Dispose() would close the underlying stream, preventing 
                // its subsequent use by the DataReader below.
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
            }

            // Create the input stream at position 0 so that the stream can be read 
            // from the beginning.
            using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
                {
                    // The encoding and byte order need to match the settings of the writer 
                    // we previously used.
                    dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                    dataReader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

                    // Once we have written the contents successfully we load the stream.
                    await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);

                    var receivedStrings = "";

                    // Keep reading until we consume the complete stream.
                    while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                    {
                        // Note that the call to readString requires a length of "code units" 
                        // to read. This is the reason each string is preceded by its length 
                        // when "on the wire".
                        uint bytesToRead = dataReader.ReadUInt32();
                        receivedStrings += dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead) + "\n";
                    }

                    // Populate the ElementsRead text block with the items we read 
                    // from the stream.
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Read: " + receivedStrings);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

make sure to use windows.storage namespaces.

the key is this line:

> IRandomAccessStream acccessStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

I am not sure what the speed implications are.